# Android save and read values from SharedPreferences

Tags: android

How to save values in preferences (and read) with quite compact way without creating several instances - i want be sure that i have only one instance of pref

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having problems with? Could you read [the guide on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonsWare is right, but as i understood, you want somehow to structure you job with Preferences, i use singleton for this, something like this:

```
public class Preferences {


    private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    private static final String LOG_TAG = Preferences.class.getSimpleName();
    private static Preferences sInstance;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private Context mContext;

    private Preferences(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public static Preferences getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Preferences(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        mEditor.putString(USERNAME, username);
        commit();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mSharedPreferences.getString(USERNAME, null);
    }

    public boolean commit() {
        return mEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

And where it is necessary write

```
Preferences.getInstance(this).setUsername("USERNAME");
```

and read

```
Preferences.getInstance(this).getUsername();
```

Answer (score 2):

A `SharedPreferences` object is a natural singleton. Your first call to read in a `SharedPreferences` (e.g., `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`) will create it. Second and subsequent calls within the same process will return that same instance. Hence, so long as you are consistent about where you get your `SharedPreferences` from, you will only ever have one instance (at most) in your process.